# Laravel multidimensional array sum with collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

My JSON output is:

```json
{
  "follow_carts":[
    {
      "id":1,
      "user_id":10001,
      "created_at":null,
      "updated_at":null,
      "followings":[
        {
          "id":1,
          "name":"Dr. Timmy Kulas Sr.",
          "email":"sumanta.php@gmail.com",
          "email_verified_at":"2022-09-15T16:17:07.000000Z",
          "created_at":"2022-09-15T16:17:08.000000Z",
          "updated_at":"2022-09-15T16:17:08.000000Z",
          "user_type":"vendor",
          "pivot":{
            "follower_id":1,
            "user_id":1
          },
          "carts":[
            {
              "id":1,
              "user_id":1,
              "level_two_id":1,
              "cart_name":"Lorem lipsum",
              "main_photo":"https://images.pexels.com/photos/2533311/pexels-photo-2533311.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2",
              "important_details":"york",
              "created_at":null,
              "updated_at":null,
              "status":1,
              "main_category_id":1,
              "opens":1
            },
            {
              "id":2,
              "user_id":1,
              "level_two_id":2,
              "cart_name":"Cafe",
              "main_photo":"https://images.pexels.com/photos/2533311/pexels-photo-2533311.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2",
              "important_details":"New York's best cafe",
              "created_at":null,
              "updated_at":null,
              "status":0,
              "main_category_id":1,
              "opens":2
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**I am trying to get total "opens" of all carts of each follow_carts.**
So in this case the result should be 2 + 1 = 3 opens.

I want to do it using collection sum but no luck.

Can anyone please give me an idea.

Comment: follows_cart is multiple or single?

Comment: and what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

If this structure remain same if follow carts remains same then you can use below

```
 $data = collect($jsonData); //convert json data into array
 $value = collect($data['follow_carts'][0]['followings'][0]['carts']);
 $sum = $value->sum('opens');
```

if follow_carts are multiple then you have to use foreach loop and follow the same process.

Comment: Follow_carts are array

Comment: Following also an array

Comment: did you try solution will it work? or you need something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop on your json !

```
$s=0;
foreach($data["follow_carts"][0]["followings"][0]['carts'] as $value){
  $s += $value["opens"];
}
```